# convert string to int use sstream

Tags: c++, string, int, sstream

We want to convert string to int using **sstream**.

But we don't know our string has an integer or not, for example it can be the ***"hello 200"*** and we want **200** in that, or it can be ***"hello"*** and there was **no solution**!

I have this code when we have only an integer in the string:

```
inline int string_to_int(string s)
{
    stringstream ss(s);
    int x;
    ss >> x;
    return x;
}
```

Now, if s = "hello 200!" or s = "hello" , how we can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple possibility which ignores bad inputs until first integer in a string:

```
bool string_to_int(string str, int &x)
{
    istringstream ss(str);

    while (!ss.eof())
    {
       if (ss >> x)
           return true;

       ss.clear();
       ss.ignore();
    }
    return false; // There is no integer!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write parser based on finite state machine and correct any input as you wish:

```
int extract_int_from_string(const char* s) {
   const char* h = s;
   while( *h ) {
      if( isdigit(*h) )
         return atoi(h);
      h+=1;
   }
   return 0;
```

}
...
int i = extract_int_from_string("hello 100");

Comment: And we do not need to index of integer in string?

Comment: I am not sure that I undestand your question correctly. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
 //You can use the following function to get the integer part in your string...
    string findDigits(string s){
    string digits="";
    int len=s.length();
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(s.at(i)>='0' && s.at(i)<='9')
        digits+=s[i];}
     return digits;}

// and call the above function inside this function below...
    int string_to_int(string s){
    string digits=findDigits(s);
    stringstream ss(digits);
    int x;
    ss >> x;
    return x;}
```